# How to remove ignored files from current commit using git commit --amend

Tags: git

I made a commit which contains lot of .o files that I want to ignore. So I created a .gitignore file and even made it default global (I put it to my home and did `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`).

Now I need to amend that commit so that these files are no longer in it before I push. However doing just `git commit -a --amend` leave the ignored files in the commit.

I need to re-apply these new ignore rules on this existing commit before I push it

How do I fix it?

Comment: You may have to remove the unwanted files from the 'Changes to be committed'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
```

and you will see the changes you've made to that commit as staged. Now unstage the unwanted files and commit only the wanted ones:

```
$ git reset HEAD *.o
$ git commit -m "commit msg"
```